# Use CLASS defined in R package (Rcpp)

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to translate a series of R codes into Rcpp wrap function.
But I do not know how to translate these codes into Rcpp wrap function.

```
dat = Surv(data[, 2], data[, 3])
fit = survfit(dat ~ 1)
```

Note that both `Surv` & `survfit` are functions defined in R package `Survival`. Class of `dat` is `Surv`, and class of `fit` is `survfit`. Both of these class are defined in package `Survival`.

Greatly appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: Both `Surv` and `survfit` are S3 classes. These are generated by attaching a class attribute to an R object, c.f. https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/setting-object-attributes/. You should consult the documentation and source code for `survival` to find the right structure for the R objects (starting point: numeric matrix and named list).

Comment: @RalfStubner Thanks for your answer. But how can I find the structures of `Surv` & `survfit`?

Comment: Do you know what S3 classes are? If yes, then inspecting the sources and documentation plus some examples should be sufficient. If not, than you will have to do some reading first, e.g. https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html

Comment: @RalfStubner Yes, I know what is S3. But I do not know where to find the sources and documentation regarding class details.

Comment: Typically the value section of the corresponding help page details the S3 structure. You can get the source of any R function by calling it without parentheses.

Comment: Thank you very much. I roughly understand how to deal with it.